# sql server connection string

Tags: sql-server-2005

I just deployed my database to my remote server. I am trying to create a connectionstring to the remote server and it won't work. I am using godaddy. I kept having this message: could not establish a connection to the database. Here is the connectionstring for the local server:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Can someone help me with the connection for the remote server? Lets say my database name is collins and my password is database, and the remote hosting server=quiz.db.4423045.hostedresource.com;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given those connection elements you mention, your connection string ought to look something like this:

```
<add name="RemoteConnectionString" 
     connectionString="server=quiz.db.4423045.hostedresource.com;database=collins;
                       user id=?????;password=database;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What you're missing is a user name for the connection to the database (or you didn't specify one) - you need to place that into the connection string as value for the `user id=` attribute.

For a great listing and explanations of all things about connection strings, you should definitely check out http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0):

First I would check that you can access ports `TCP 1433` and `UDP 1434` on that server (you need also the UDP port since you are using the `SQLEXPRESS` instance in the server).

You can check that using [nmap/ZenMap](http://nmap.org/) ([Download](http://nmap.org/dist/nmap-5.21-setup.exe)) or any other port scanner. The ports should be reported as ***open***.